# Forwarding naked domain to www

Tags: dns, domains

I successfully mapped my `www.mydomain.com` to my Google site (as described [here](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/99448)).

However I would like to forward also my naked domain (`mydomain.com`) to end up in `www.mydomain.com`.

I assume I should modify 'A' DNS record in my provider but what IP should I point it to?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [get-site-ip.com](http://get-site-ip.com/) to get the IP of a webiste.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?